# Set cache expiration?

Tags: html, caching

I tested my site with Chrome and got the following recommendation:

```
The following resources are missing a cache expiration. Resources that do not specify an expiration may not be cached by browsers:
style.css
jquery.marquee.js
jquery.marquee.css
logo.png
```

How do I set the cache expiration for these files?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Following the [*Yahoo! Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site,*](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)
you should [Add an Expires or a Cache-Control Header](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires) and [Configure ETags](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags).

How you actually go about configuring the server to do this depends on far more information than you have provided in the question.

Answer (score 18):

One of the way to Set cache expiration is by using .htaccess file.

Below code will set expiration for it's respective file type, e.g. for CSS files expiration will be 14 days.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
   ExpiresActive on
   ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
   ExpiresByType image/x-ico "access plus 1 year"
   ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 14 days"
   ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 14 days"
   ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 14 days"
   ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 14 days"
   ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 14 days"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: is there a way to clear theese caches when I want (after update for instance)?

Comment: @Reign.85 : You can't force the browser to clear caches. You can use versioning of your files like `style.css` to `style.css?v1.1` or renaming the file will solve the issue.

Comment: If I removed that code from .htaccess would the browser then get the latest version, without renaming files (or using versioning)?

Comment: **No (need versioning)**, Since your last cached file is in cache browser will not request server for that file. Only when the cache expires or do force reload (CTRL + F5), browser will request that file from server.

Answer (score 1):

If this question pertains to caching of javascript or css that are a part of your tomcat application directory; you may like to examine the /conf/web.xml file.

Typically the mime mapping available here is
    <mime-mapping>
           <extension>js</extension>
           <mime-type>application/javascript</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

In apache the default directive is
   ExpiresByType text/javascript           "access plus <specify your timeframe>"

You may like to change the apache directive to application/javascript or change the tomcat mime mapping to text/javascript and this will set the expiration to your timeframe.