# html page refreshing cache

Tags: html, caching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set cache expiration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134425/set-cache-expiration)

I am releasing a new version of my HTML page. 
But in most of the browsers(customers' browser), the older version is shown.

The problem should be cache. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried CTRL+F5 ?

Comment: Actually i want  the users to see the new version. I cannot communicate to them to press ctrl+R or ctrl+F5

Comment: Look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7134482/1247955)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `no-cache` header. Give this inside your `<head></head>`:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

Comment: it can be added in the new version. But how can i force refresh older version which is already cached by browsers.

Comment: What kind of an application is it? If this is the case, you can't do anything.

Comment: change the file name/url and be careful about [cache control](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires)

Comment: its jus a web site running in asp.net 4.0, iis 6