# How to download google jquery library and style sheet only once across pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I just put my first website into the real world for testing, but I found it is a lot slower than my expectation. In the network/timeline section in console I found that for every page redirect, the user have to download JQuery library and CSS again.

I have the below two lines of code across all my php files. I wondered what is the best way to download them only once.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">


<script type="text/javascript" src="/script/googleapis.js"></script>
```

Comment: I can think of two possibilities. write a simple single page web app that uses jquery ajax with some php crud to manipulate the dom with your choice of clientside templating ... instead of using redirects, or you could try storing the entire jquery library in the browsers local storage. I would try for the single page web app approach.

Answer (score 2):

If your browser re-downloads static assets like CSS files or JS libraries, it could be due to a bad caching policy set by your server.

Your visitors should only download these kind of static assets on the first page, for any subsequent pages browsed on your site, these assets should be loaded from the browser cache. They would appear in your "network" tab in the console as:
[image: CSS assets load from the browser cache]

Have a look at that question which details how to set the cache expiration policy: [Set cache expiration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134425/set-cache-expiration)