# How to fix cache bug?

Tags: php, html, browser

I update home page code on daily basis. now from last 4-5 days I am facing the issue of browser cache. whenever I am updating any article, Its not reflecting instantly till I refresh it. when I refresh the URL then its working perfectly but every-time its loading the default home page. can anybody help to fix this type of bug?

Comment: try setting the `expiration time` to some thing like `1hour` or so, its a rule for the `.htaccess` link here: https://varvy.com/pagespeed/leverage-browser-caching.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set cache expiration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134425/set-cache-expiration)

Comment: I have tried .htaccess but still it is have same problem on mobile and desktop...I added blow code in .htaccess <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires 0
</IfModule>